# Booting linux from grub2 gets kernel panic - root=null

Tags: linux, boot, grub, uefi, efi

I'm doing my own homebrewed version of linux. The distro works fine but I need to update it to use EFI and GPT partitions. My problem now is that I can't for the life of me get grub2 to boot it. I install the distro on the machine and it boots to the EFI command prompt (this is what I want for now.) From there I load grub. My grub.cfg file is obviously flawed since it goes straight to the command line. I do the following commands:

```
set root=(hd0,gpt1)
linux bzImage... root=/dev/sda3
boot
```

The kernel starts booting and then panics because it can't load the root partition - it says `root=null` which seems to me to be that grub didn't pass the "`root=/dev/sda3`" kernel option in.  I know that both /dev/sda3 and the kernel are fine since I can boot from the EFI command line by going `bzImage... root=/dev/sda3` and it works with no problems but I need to get grub2 up and running.

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Comment: Can you boot up a live USB stick and check that the partitions still exist? This is what happens when the kernel can't find /

Comment: I can boot from the UEFI command line and linux runs properly I just can't get GRUB to boot linux.